# Pole placement gains tuning

Tags: control, pid, tuning, matlab

given my control system 
[image]

I have found the region of the complex space that satisfies my specifications, determining poles position in 0.5 +- 0.2i. 
[image]
Now I want to find the gains that fix the desider pole (with matlab), but I have not understand well how to do it: anyone can suggest me an example on how to do that, with or without matlab?
Thanks

Edit: in the first image the sum blocks are +-, not ++

Comment: Sorry for not having enough time to type the complete answer, but this should help you in case noone else responds in the meantime: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_state_feedback

Comment: ok I will look at the link, thanks @DamjanDakic

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you'd aim to place the poles in $-0.5 \pm 0.2 \cdot i$ for stability reasons.

In the s-domain, the transfer function is:
$$
\frac{\Phi_c}{\Phi}=\frac{K_p}{s^2+K_ds+K_p}.
$$

Computing the closed-loop poles, hence the roots of the characteristics polynomial $s^2+K_ds+K_p$, gives you:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
K_d=1 \\
K_p=1.16/4
\end{array}.
$$